# PHP/Imagick: Custom composite blending

Tags: php, imagick

I'd like to create my own blending method for compositing semi-transparent images using PHP/Imagick.

Currently I'm using `exportimagepixels`/`importimagepixels` for this, but this is very memory-hungry and relatively slow.

Is there any way to build an expression like in `fxImage` using multiple images or some other method that may make this faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two images, the pixel from the first and second images can be referenced by `u` and `v`

There is an example from https://www.imagemagick.org/script/fx.php

convert -channel red logo: -flop logo: -resize "20%" -fx "(u+v)/2" image.jpg

I think in Imagick, you can make an Imagick object that contains two images like this:

```
$im1 = new Imagick(realpath('./src1.png'));
$im2 = new Imagick(realpath('./src1.png'));
$im1->addImage($im2);
```

And then call fxImage on $im1

Comment: From the looks of it, that is exactly what I need. Will try it out!